# Adding spinners to MenuManager

Tags: java, jface

```
IMenuManager submenu = new MenuManager("Menu item");

        submenu.add(new Action("Sub menu item") {
             @Override
             public void run() {
             }
         });
```

I want Spinner to be added to submenu. In above code i have added " sub menu item" to submenu.
Similarly is there any way i can add Spinner to it.
I want to use  in place of "sub menu item" as interger input 1 to 100000 and able to increment and decrement by clicking the up and down button.

Comment: Spinners are not supported in menus.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

Your alternative solution would be to create yourself a faux-context-menu, with a **[popup composite](http://palea.cgrb.oregonstate.edu/svn/jaiswallab/Annotation/src/ie/dcu/swt/PopupComposite.java)**, on which you will put your spinner widget.

I suggest to ought to find an alternative to this alternative (i.e. change your UI). You have a lot of UI/UX cases to cover.

Comment: My customer requirement is right click option should be in Jface

Comment: @Priya JFace is OS native. Windows (example) does not have spinners in menus. How about opening a small dialog? Or including the spinner above the table? Or in a cell editor?